# Backup Exec 2012 not backing up SQL logs

Tags: sql-server, backupexec

I am unable to make BUE 2012 backup (and truncate) the SQL Logs from our Microsoft SQL 2005 and SQL 2008 database servers that are set to FULL mode. No errors are being reported, but the Transaction logs are not being truncated and continue to grow.

I have already reviewed these two Symantec notes:

http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/how-backup-sql-logs-and-truncate-them-be-2012

http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=HOWTO74429

I have created screenshots of the job settings and uploaded them to Image Shack as follows:

1: Backup Properties: http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/5034/ddwx.jpg

2: Options - Schedule: http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/8697/vc5y.jpg

3: Options - Storage: http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/1231/kqwx.jpg

4: Options - Test Run: http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/9486/p2sb.jpg

5: Options - Verify: http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/8334/txlq.jpg

6: Options - AOF: http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/5760/57oh.jpg

7: Options - Security: http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/2145/adi0.jpg

8: Options - Pre/Post Commands: http://img547.imageshack.us/img547/8243/sca4.jpg

9: Options - Microsoft SQL: http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/4628/8eek.jpg

9: Options - Exclusions: http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/8192/yt0r.jpg

10: Job Summary: http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/6010/rf6l.jpg

11: BUE Version: http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/8184/k0rz.jpg

Any assistance will be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to run/schedule a log backup job with truncate but it looks like you're running a Full backup.

Comment: Opps, I made a mistake with the 1st link, to the Symantec article on how to backup SQL Logs in 2012.  Fixed now.  It is rather confusingly different to the previous versions of BUE! BE 2012 requires you to do a full SQL database backup before you can backup SQL logs.